# PyAudio Installtion Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pyaudio

I'm trying to run program which requires PyAudio.
I have 0.2.8 version but it requires 0.2.9 version.
Terminal tells me to update my pip.
After Doing also it shows my old Command only [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiaVc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4vGj.png)

Comment: Don't include images with text, try to include the text itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your setuptools:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python
```

or

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py | python
```

Comment: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-5661.write-test'



    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative

Comment: sudo wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python

or

sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py | python

Comment: Error: Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

Comment: I 'm The Admin.

Comment: Run the command somewhere else, anywhere else, wherever you have write access.